# Update values incrementally in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

One field of my table's field is set to 0 for all rows. But I want to update the incremental value by step 1 in an update query.

How can I do that in mysql?

Comment: To clarify: You are asking how to change an existing data set so it has incrementing numbers?

Comment: no,i add this field recently so it is set to 0 by default and it should not be auto increment for feature.i just want to fill it with valid data.hope i could clarify it.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql> select @i := 0;
mysql> update bar set c = (select @i := @i + 1);
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SET @a = 0;  
UPDATE customers SET id = @a:=@a+1;
```

You can go for this as well.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can implement this in php ?

Comment: Worked fine. Thank You SushilKumar, your suggestion was easy and effective.

Comment: any way to fix the order of the table?

Comment: @FlyingTurtle add an ORDER BY to the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 7):

One line solution:

```
UPDATE tablename AS a, (SELECT @a := 0) AS b SET a.fieldname = @a:=@a+1
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a new table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column instead of the original column, inserting all data from the old into the new table, and then renaming the new and deleting the old.

Another way is to run your update query with a [MySQL variable](http://blog.sriunplugged.com/mysql/display-row-number-mysql-select-query/) that generates an increasing number for each row (to emulate the ROW_NUMBER() function found in other DBMS systems).

Comment: as i remember i did it before using mysql variables but i don't remember the solution at this time. ;(

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way for me is to drop the field and re-create it with auto-increment.